# jQuery input keypress event in iframe to parent not triggering function

Tags: jquery, iframe, keypress, keydown, keyup

I have nested iframes in a document.
  I have an input field in the parent window that triggers a function on keyup to fetch data base on the input. I don't have access to the keyup function so I want to basically insert a string and triggers a keyup event from within an iframe so the function can fire.

My code:

```
 parent.$("#my_input").focus();
 parent.$("#my_input").trigger(jQuery.Event('keyup', {keycode: 13}));
```

I've bind an alert event to test if it actually triggers the event. It does. But the keyup function doesn't get called.
If I physically press the key, it works but not when I trigger it using jQuery.

I've searched all over stackoverflow but can't find anything similar.

I've tried

```
  parent.$("#my_input").focus();
  parent.$("#my_input").keypress();
  parent.$("#my_input").keyup();
  parent.$("#my_input").blur();
```

Also tried using other key code like left arrow, or a random character. None of them works.

Any suggestion would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the iframe content documents all on the same domain, and do they use `window.domain = ...` to explicitly declare that?

Comment: Ya they are on the same domain

Comment: Do you set `window.domain = 'mydomain.com';` in the script? Try adding it to the script running within the iframe, and the one outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ev       = jQuery.Event('keyup');
    ev.which = 13;

parent.$("#my_input").focus();
parent.$("#my_input").trigger(ev);
```

Not sure what `parent` is, but chaining it with a selector does seem strange?

You're sure it's not just

```
$("#my_input").focus().trigger(ev);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tEuLQ/)

Comment: I've done that as well. It doesn't work. The event gets triggered but the function attached to it doesn't.
But if I physically strike a key, it works...